# I have a problem with changing back from werewolf to human

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim, the-elder-scrolls-5-skyrim-vr

I used the Ring of Hircine a couple of times and now it has been 9 days since my transformation. I haven’t fed on any corpses and I'm stuck as a werewolf. Please help.

Comment: Are you using the cursed ring, or the non-cursed version? Are you using any mods?

Comment: Just the non-cursed ring, no mods